# Creating a file structure within Kubernetes for any object

Tags: kubernetes

The environment given to us at my job is such that I may have 40 or 50 Kubernetes objects of the same type in a single Kubernetes namespace. So, for example, `kubectl get deployments` may list 40 or 50 different deployments in my current namespace.

Is there a way to add any sort of file structure to objects in a Kubernetes namespace? For example:

```
├── deployments
│   ├── deployment_group_A
│   │   ├── deployment1.yml
│   │   ├── deployment2.yml
│   ├── deployment_group_B
│   │   ├── deployment3.yml
│   │   ├── deployment4.yml
```

Is it possible to create some sort of structure like that within Kubernetes, for any Kubernetes object?

Comment: The only particular organization structure within Kubernetes is grouping things into Namespaces; there's no further structure within these.